# Using the HANDLE returned by LoadImageA in WNDCLASSEXA (instead of HICON)

Tags: windows, rust, windows-rs

I'm new to both Rust and win32 (using windows-rs), and have been trying to understand both. However, I'm running into issues setting the icon for the window class I'm trying to create. [The example](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/a80df1e5c610b2da75401337a8e4d5b1b29c86c2/crates/samples/windows/create_window/src/main.rs#L13-L21) leaves the `hIcon` field of the `WNDCLASSA` it sets up blank. While I've already conquered the issue of using resource files to reference the icons, I must still load the icon and get a handle to it in order to use it. Several examples and other sources reference using [LoadIconA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona) but, as noted on the page, the function has been superseded by [LoadImageA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea).

The issue arises when I replace my use of `LoadIconA` with `LoadImageA` - While the former returns an HICON, the latter simply returns a HANDLE. If I understand the Windows docs correctly, both HICON and HANDLE are both themselves integer handles used by the operating system to reference the loaded image. How do I make use of the HANDLE returned by LoadImageA in places where Rust expects an HICON? Is there some way to cast between these two types?

Comment: When you load an icon using `LoadImage`, you can convert it to an `HICON` using `HICON(h.0);` (where `h` is the return value of `LoadImage`). `LoadImage` can load and return several different image types, and its return value is essentially a type-erased version that needs to be converted back into one of those image types. If you don't want to deal with this, you can keep using `LoadIcon` instead.

Comment: This worked - I suppose what I was looking for was that particular syntax to convert it over. Thanks!